# Backup Drive Issue: Seagate backup plus 1TB in not getting detected

Tags: mount, hard-drive, backup, external-hdd

I just bought a new Seagate backup plus, 1 TB external backup drive, USB 3.0, it is working good with my windows, but when I login into my Ubuntu 12.04 it does not get detected by any way.

Before purchasing it, I did a short research to find out if its going to work with Ubuntu, and I found a thread here (askubuntu) justifying that SGate-1TB ext drive is going to work(lost the link for that thread). I tried with my other machines with 12.04 running - No success, however with windows it works great.

I tried to see if getting detected in

```
    fdisk -l (doesn’t show up in the list)
```

Cant see in /mnt - Cant mount it. (checked with root and normal users)

After failing with all attempts, I check if its getting detected at all , even the USB.

```
    lsusb
```

with some ray of hope it showed in terminal

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bc2:a013 Seagate RSS LLC
```

[image]

Then I opened the Disk Utility, it display me bank, something like this. 
[image]

Please help me. I don’t want to be dependent on Windows for this. I have been a great admirer of Linux Ubuntu since from the time I installed it my computer, never crashed or gave any issue except for a superblock once long time back. Please Help.

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same screen when I put it in the USB 2.0 but when I plugged it into the USB 3.0 port then it would be detected and you can see it with lsusb.

Comment: This also solved the problem on my XPS 13 machine - one port is USB2 and the other is USB3.

Comment: i had the opposite - usb3 port doesnt work but usb2 port does. lol

Answer (score 2):

I have had an experience with a Seagate product a couple of years ago that required security software and drivers (Windows based) to "unlock" and make the drive appear once attached via USB.  I had to disable it to use on my linux machines.  Sorry I do not have more detail but hopefully this is another avenue for your troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks for your humble comment, i will try with ur point neil. And if i find anything then i would really contribute the steps here... I am so confident that there is a way for sure. Linux have never let me down ever. I hope i'll find soon.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue at first, but it was just because my laptop PC was in a docking station and I was plugging the Seagate drive into one of the laptop's usb ports. When I plugged it in to a usb port on the docking station, it showed up in ubuntu 13.04's launcher bar with no problem, mounted on `/media/username/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/`

My guess is that it's an issue with the power supplied by the usb port. I didn't see the power-on light on the drive when plugged in to the notebook directly, but did see it when plugged in to the docking station....

Comment: :'( didnt work for me. On ubuntu I can see the power on HDD. MY friend have a docking station. Failed there too. :/

Answer (score -1):

This was easily remedied on my 5TB seagate by 
sudo nautilus
and then changing the permissions to the drive and its sub folders.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on the process involved. Which permission did you set exactly?

Comment: Ok do this
1.Enter nautilus

    sudo nautilus

2.Navigate to directories properties you want access to

    Right click drive select properties from the drop down menu.

3. Navigate to permissions tab
4. Chamge permissions to create and delete

Comment: [edit] your answer to provide additional details. Don't leave the in comments.

Answer (score -1):

Change all permissions to create and delete and make sure owner is set to Me and the group is set to root also change permission to enclosed files recursively...alternatively you can install a new OS set your main drives mount point to / and your usb hard drives mount point to /home when using Plex I found the later way is more stable.

Comment: Why did I get down voted on these answers?

Answer (score -1):

I had the problem where the Seagate 7 wouldn't work in Linux Mint 17.2 KDE. as it comes formatted in exFAT, after a quick format with NTFS it works with Windows and Linux

Kilowatt